# Pixel-size translations between subsequent mobile phone pictures taken on tripod?

Tags: tripod, image-stabilization

I am trying to take two identical pictures that are exactly the same in every way except for noise. However, I am finding it incredibly difficult due to the tiny angular movements that seem to always happen between shots on both my DSLR and mobile phone. I know about shutter shock and the vibrations that come from a moving mirror, but my phone has no moving parts (as far as I know). So, why is it that if I take two pictures in quick succession, using a remote so that my hands don't touch the phone, and using a tripod, I observe a minute pixel-size translations between images taken in immediate succession? (It also happens with my DSLR, but that's easier to explain because of its mechanical vibrations.)

Explanations I have thought of are,

- My tripod is settling due to gravity and latent tension after moving it.
- Some kind of internal image stabilization that I can't turn off is translating the shots differently every time.

Why do you think my images are coming out slightly different? Is taking two completely identical photos a fool's errand or is there a way to get it done?

Comment: To what end do you need pixel perfect dupes?

Comment: Answers from [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/97144/how-to-take-2-photos-of-the-same-scene-and-keep-them-registered) may be of help.

Comment: This seems to be an [X→Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please ask the question that is the root cause of your problem, rather than a question about how to accomplish what you perceive to be the solution to the root problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiny sensors with huge megapixel counts have sensels that may be only a micron wide. Virtually anything could cause the sensor to move a few microns. Looking at your phone *may* be enough to shift the image a pixel or two.